# Gregório Amúrrio: dates of birth and death

Tags: 18th-century, california

[Gregório Amúrrio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorio_Amurrio) was a Franciscan missionary in California during the late 1700s.  He was one of the five original missionaries to Alta California, and the co-founder of Mission San Juan Capistrano.

When was he born and when did he die?

Comment: You know your researching a tough topic when the only thing that comes up is the question itself. :P

Comment: Can you expand the question a little more to include why it is that you believe he is historically significant? Citing the wikipedia page isn't really sufficient imo.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Encyclopedia of Frontier Biography](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iXP58ROs8mgC) (p23), he was born at Bastida, Spain in **1744** and died **post 1784**.

Comment: Geiger, the biographer of California Franciscan missionaries, wrote that no record of Amurrio's death has been found.